# How to align big one line string in visual studio

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio

Hello i have maybe stupid question, how can i write for example

this line of code, which may represent big sql statement (dozens of rows)

```
string sql = "SELECT A,B,C FROM TableX";
```

to following block code format, which is more transparent, simpler to edit but i need also to have one line string ?

```
string sql = "SELECT A,
B,
C
FROM 
TableX";
```

But i dont want to have \n characters in the string, i want that block was also ONE LINE string.

Thank you

Comment: create a `constant = \n` and use it in the string declaration for clearer code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add `@` in front of the string. This turns it into a *[verbatim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)* string which is allowed to span multiple lines.

This does introduce line breaks (and possible lots of extra spaces, depending on indention), but you can easily remove those.

Comment: Thank you now i can declare that string block, but i am having trouble with this end of lines.. SQLQuery = SQLQuery.Replace("\n", ""); Console.WriteLine(SQLQuery) seems to show only last line, dont know why ?

Comment: @Muflix Check the string in the debugger. Hint: On Windows, a line break is encoded with "\r\n", not "\n".